# Infopath repeating section drop down duplicate value check

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath, infopath-rules

I have drop down list on repeating section which is populated with "Languages" list from XML file. I would like to restrict duplicate language selection in the drop down but it's not working.

Here is the interface,

[image]

Repeating section is bind with "Questions" section and drop down field is bind with "Label1"

[image]

Here is data source of drop down list,

[image]

I tried adding following formula on "result" field to get the count of duplicate selection but it is returning 0 all the time,

```
count(Label1[text() = preceding-sibling::*/../Questions/Question/Label1/text()]) + count(Label1[text() = following-sibling::*/../Questions/Question/Label1/text()])
```

Any help will be must appreciated.